# simplifying two queries into one with the same types linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I have this code:

```
var commentData = from o in quack.BlogComments
                  join u in quack.AdminUsers
                  on o.UserId equals u.AdminUserId
                  where blogid == o.BlogId
                  select new
                  {
                      o.Comment,
                      o.CommentDate,
                      u.FirstName,
                      u.LastName
                  };

var commentData2 = from o in quack.BlogComments
                  join u in quack.RegularUsers
                  on o.UserId equals u.RegularUserId
                  where blogid == o.BlogId
                  select new
                  {
                      o.Comment,
                      o.CommentDate,
                      u.FirstName,
                      u.LastName
                  };

var l = commentData.ToList();
l.AddRange(commentData2);
```

As you can see above I am doing **2 different queries** to the database and then adding them together to generate a **single list** to be used in the `gridview`.

What I want is to only use 1 query to the database and will result to two of those table combined.

How can I do it? is it possible with multiple joins?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Concat`:

```
var commentData = (from o in quack.BlogComments
                   join u in quack.AdminUsers
                   on o.UserId equals u.AdminUserId
                   where blogid == o.BlogId
                   select new
                   {
                       o.Comment,
                       o.CommentDate,
                       u.FirstName,
                       u.LastName
                   }).Concat(from o in quack.BlogComments
                             join u in quack.RegularUsers
                             on o.UserId equals u.RegularUserId
                             where blogid == o.BlogId
                             select new
                             {
                                 o.Comment,
                                 o.CommentDate,
                                 u.FirstName,
                                 u.LastName
                             });

var l = commentData.ToList();
```

Comment: does it make more sense to write `var l = commentData.Concat(commentData2).ToList()` without that nested queries? It would also be very nice to notice, that Lint to Sql would be able to form a sql query with `UNION`, resulting in a single round-trip to the database.

Comment: Yes, would give exact same result.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek would this still result to 2 different queiry to database?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov So Union will result in 2 tables adding each other?

Comment: @gameon No, it should be just one query. `Concat` will be translated into `UNION ALL` within generated SQL.